# Link column with a static text using django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I cannot find a replacement for the `LinkColumn` in the new versions of `django-tables2`. Author states that `LinkColumn` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. But the new `linkify` solution is poorly documented and doesn't have all the features of the old version. For example, I have this column:

```
    edit = tables.LinkColumn(
        'wagtailadmin_pages:edit', args=[A('page.pk')],
        text='Edit'
    )
```

It displays a link to the wagtail admin edit page called `Edit`. There's simply no way to achieve the same using `linkify` because `linkify` only works if you have valid `accessor` on the column. But accessor cannot return same static text for all rows (unless I modify the model to add a dummy property - but this particular model is in the 3rd party package and it would feel like a duct tape solution anyway).

In all other cases, column will not display a link. I've studied the source code and it seems that such case is simply not supported by the django-tables2 > 2.0.0.

Is there any clean and understandable way to construct a link column with a static link text using `linkify`?

Comment: You could override `get_absolute_url` on the model and just pass `linkify=True`, perhaps, but that depends on the model.

Alternatively, you could define a vanilla `edit = tables.Column(...)` and create a `render_edit` in your `tables.Table` subclass

Comment: I cannot override `get_absolute_url` or any other property of the model because it's from `django-wagtail` package. Thanks for suggesting overriding `render_edit` method - I was so focused on trying to make the pesky `linkify` work that I totally forgot about trying other approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question. It seems that it is impossible to fully replace `LinkColumn` with the `linkify` feature. The following code solves my problem:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import mark_safe

import django_tables2 as tables

from wagtail.core.models import PageRevision


class WagtailRevisionsTable(tables.Table):
    title = tables.Column(
        accessor='page.title',
        linkify=lambda record: record.page.url,
        verbose_name='Title'
    )
    edit = tables.Column(
        accessor='page.pk'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PageRevision
        fields = ('title', 'created_at', 'user', 'edit')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'

    def render_edit(self, value):
        url = reverse('wagtailadmin_pages:edit', args=[value])
        return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}">Edit</a>')
```

The code with the old `LinkColumn` was much more concise, I don't understand the reason for change and documentations really doesn't help. There's simply not enough information on `linkify` or `render_col` methods.

So I hope this answer will help some poor soul trying to port old code to the django-tables2 >= 2.0.